# How to pass object of form_for to partial rendered in file `action_name.js.erb`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have used an action to display all topics of a course, when that course is selected. Now I want to use virtual attribute to display a field `number_question` on form for each topic to use can enter a number. My model:

```
class GeneralExam < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course_id, :description
  attr_accessor :numbe_question
end
```

This is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @general_exam, defaults: { error: false } do |f| %>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>General Exam information</legend>
                <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
                    <%= f.association :course, collection: current_user.courses, prompt: "Choose Course for exam"  %>
                    <%= f.input :name %>
                    <%= f.input :description, input_html: { rows: 2, class: 'span6' } %>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Choose number question for topics</legend>
                <div id="list_topics">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <%= f.submit class: "new_resource" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my action:

```
  def update_topics
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @topics = @course.topics
  end
```

My `update_topics.js.erb`

```
$('#list_topics').html("<%= j (render('general_exams/list_topics')) %>")
```

My `_list_topics.html.erb` partial:

```
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <h5><%= topic.name %></h3>
    <%# f.input :number_question, input_html: { name: "number_question[#{topic.id}]" } %>
<% end %>
```

But if I want to display input field, I have to have a `f` object, but when I render `_list_topics`, I didn't have. So I want to ask how to pass `f` object of form to partial `_list_topics`?

Or someone can tell me how to use jquery to  add input field after `h5` element on the form, thank so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are some different approaches to solve the problem. Two of them (the ones i:

1) You could define a different form to post the number_question data to another controller action.
2) Submit the number_question using jquery's change callback when user finishes updating the field value.

I think first option is better and easier to code. You will end up with something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @general_exam, defaults: { error: false } do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>General Exam information</legend>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
            <%= f.association :course, collection: current_user.courses, prompt: "Choose Course for exam"  %>
            <%= f.input :name %>
            <%= f.input :description, input_html: { rows: 2, class: 'span6' } %>
    </fieldset>
    <%= f.submit class: "new_resource" %>
<% end %>
```

Then, you'll have a different form on the same template (to submit topic numbers):

```
<%= simple_form_for @general_exam, url: whatever_is_your_new_topics_number_path, defaults: { error: false } do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
        <div id="list_topics">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

You will continue to respond with your JS partial, replacing div's content accordingly to topics data.

Comment: But if so on the form now I will have two button submit? I'm not clear yet :(

Comment: No... You will have two different forms on the same page.

Comment: But how can I make input fields? It's seem like when I have one form.

Comment: The entire secondary form will be inside your partial (.js.erb) file

Comment: I want each topic has a input field, but render that maybe I will display all topic with only one input field